# Why do I get a Decimal data error when I run this SQLRPGLE program

Tags: db2, rpgle

I'm working on an sqlrpgle program, when I run, I get the message: Decimal-data error occurred (C G D F)

```
**FREE
//******************************************************************/
//Program: States
// Written by: Victor Hernandez
// Date: 1/24/2024
// Purpose: This program Is a lab that demonstrates embedded SQL by reading
// the currency file in FLIGHT2023
// ***************************************************************/

//--------------------------------Control Options
ctl-opt Option(*NODEBUGIO) DFTACTGRP(*NO);

//--------------------------------Declare Files
dcl-f  STATES Printer usage(*Output) oflind(EndOfPage);

//--------------------------------Constants
dcl-c EndOfFile '02000';

//--------------------------------Stand Alone Variables
dcl-s EndOfPage Ind Inz(*on);

dcl-ds ZIPDS Extname('ZIPPF') end-ds;


//--------------------------------Main

EXEC SQL DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT * FROM ZIPPF
   FOR read only;

EXEC SQL OPEN cur;

dou SQLSTATE = EndOfFile;
 EXEC SQL FETCH cur INTO :ZIP, :CITY, :STATE;

 Exsr Overflow;

 WRITE DETAILS;


ENDDO;

EXEC SQL CLOSE cur;

*INLR = *ON;
RETURN;

 BEGSR OVERFLOW;
   IF ENDOFPAGE;
     WRITE HEADER;
     ENDOFPAGE =*OFF;
   ENDIF;
 ENDSR;
```

I tried to hit prompt on the CRTSQLRPGI command to see if I could change something but didn't find a way to ignore decimal data errors. The print file shows the headers in an absolute record, but the data, which is in a relative record, does not show up

Comment: You didn't mention which statement is getting the decimal data error. Please update your post to say which statement is getting the error, and which variable has invalid decimal data. The error message will say which statement it is, and then you can look at the variables used on that statement to see which variable has bad decimal data.

Comment: As @BarbaraMorris correctly pointed out, you did not provide any information that would allow you to even approximately guess where and why the error occurs.
It is unclear what types of fields are contained in ZIPPF.
It is not clear what types of fields ZIP, CITY, STATE are in the STATES printer file.
It is not clear at what point the error occurs.
Without all this information, it is impossible to give you any useful or meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to ignore decimal data errors, so there's no option to do that. Instead, you should figure out what is causing the error and fix it.

If you run your program in debug, it will stop on the statement that gets the error, and then you can inspect the variables used on that statement. For packed and zoned variables, look at the values in hex to see which variable is incorrect. Packed variables should have the hex form x'nnnnnF' or x'nnnnnD' where n is 0-9, for example x'12345F'. Zoned variables should have the hex form x'FnFnFnFn' or x'FnFnFnDn', for example x'F1F2F3F4F5'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `ZIP` contains non-numeric characters (my guess anyway).
Answer the Decimal Data Error Message with 'D' and look at the formatted dump. You will see the hexadecimal interpretation of your data. That makes it easy to find the culprit field.